# Genitive/possessive 's via XLIFF

Tags: xliff

is there a way to determine whether a genitive s has to be appended to a person's representation (i.e. the name).
For example, in English, it is

- Petra's cape
- Thomas' cape
- Liz' cape

(the latter one is only AFAIK because it's pronounced with a trailing s without actually having one); whereas in German, it would be

- Petras Umhang (cape)
- Thomas' Umhang
- Liz' Umhang

What would be the best way to handle this via XLIFF?

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how this can be related to an interchange format like Xliff? Because specifically in case of German, one can define a variable for person's name ("%1 cape" -> "%1 Umhang") and render the possessive genitive according to the rules (e.g. "(.*[s|z])$" -> "$1**'**", "(.*[^s|z])$" -> "$1s", etc.) upon output.